# What is this book about virtual reality piloting?

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to remember what book this is for some time; it's a children's or teen's book.

All I remember about it is that there is a sort of arcade place where all the kids hang out and they get a new game that is like a spaceship virtual reality game and all the kids team up and play the game. The protagonists were of course the best at the game.

That's as much as I remember... I know it sounds very typical but does this ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: Interesting, and yes the question is quite vague, can you check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) and see if that helps to jog your memory? Good luck.

Comment: This sounds a little like Ender's Game - but that's well known enough (and has enough other elements) that it seems unlikely that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I agree with RDFozz, definitely sounds like Enders Game but there isn't enough to go on in the question to be absolutely certain.